# PyX not installed correctly when using scapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy, pdflatex, pyx

I am trying to use scapy in python 3.6 to parse pcap files, and of the features I am trying to use is pdfdump.

```
from scapy.all import *
packets = rdpcap('***path***/nitroba.pcap')
for packet in packets[0:1]:
  packet.psdump("isakmp_pkt.eps",layer_shift=1)
```

And I am getting the following error:
"ImportError: PyX and its depedencies must be installed"

Obviously I installed it, and a simple "import pyx" works, but the error persists. I did some digging and found that the problem originates in this code:

```
def _test_pyx():
"""Returns if PyX is correctly installed or not"""
try:
    with open(os.devnull, 'wb') as devnull:
        r = subprocess.check_call(["pdflatex", "--version"], stdout=devnull, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except:
    return False
else:
    return r == 0
```

when executed, it determines if pyx is installed correctly, but it says "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified".

Ideas?

Answer (score 8):

In my case (Ubuntu 18, scapy 2.4.3), I had to install pdflatex, i.e.,

```
sudo apt install texlive-latex-base
```

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer myself - when I entered the scapy command line interface it said that I needed to install miktex which is a dependency of PyX, so I did.
The second error simply looks like a bug - it looks like there is a missing "import os" statement in the packet.py module, but there is an os.startfile in line 531.

I added it, and it worked:)

Comment: I’ve reported the import bug

Answer (score 1):

Its currently 2022 in the future and this works for me with Jupyer labs running on Ubuntu 20.04

`pip install pyx`

At least this works for me:

```
from scapy.all import *

pkt = IP()

pkt.canvas_dump()
```

[image]